# How do I acces the methods within the extended class?

Tags: java

I have the following:

main.java

```
public class main {
    public static  void main(String[] args){
        Player startingPitcher = new Player("Doug", "Mellon",
                "Pitcher", 29);

        startingPitcher.setThrowingArm("right");
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
class Player
{
    private String firstName, lastName, position;
    private int age;

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName, String position, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.position = position;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    private void setFirstName(String newFirstName){
        this.firstName = newFirstName;
    }

    private String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    private void setLastName(String newLastName){
        this.lastName = newLastName;
    }

    private String getPosition(){
        return this.position;
    }

    private void setPosition(String newPosition){
        this.position = newPosition;
    }

    private int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }

    private void setAge(int newAge){
        this.age = newAge;
    }
}
```

Pitcher.java

```
public class Pitcher extends Player{

    public String throwingArm;
    public int fastballMPH;


    public Pitcher(String firstName, String lastName, String position, int age,
                   String throwingArm, int fastballMPH) {
        super(firstName, lastName, position, age);
        this.throwingArm = throwingArm;
        this.fastballMPH = fastballMPH;
    }

    public String getThrowingArm(){
        return this.throwingArm;
    }

    public void setThrowingArm(String newThrowingArm){
        this.throwingArm = newThrowingArm;
    }

    private int getFastballMPH(){
        return this.fastballMPH;
    }

    private void setFastballMPH(int newFastballMPH){
        this.fastballMPH = newFastballMPH;
    }
}
```

My main is throwing the following error:

> Error:(6, 24) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   setThrowingArm(java.lang.String)   location: variable startingPitcher
>   of type Player

I understand the error - I think - but I thought you could access the methods if you were using inheritance.

How can I set the throwing arm for the Player object in my main?

Sorry if this question is worded poorly. If there is anything I can add to clarify my question, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you all very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Variable `startingPitcher` in method `main()`, of class `main`, is an instance of `Player` and not an instance of `Pitcher`, hence it has no `setThrowingArm()` method.

You need to create an instance of `Pitcher`, i.e.

```java
Pitcher startingPitcher = new Pitcher("Doug", "Mellon", "pitcher", 29, "right", 90);
```

Note that this is what the error message is telling you, namely that variable `startingPitcher` is an instance of `Player` (and **not** an instance of `Pitcher`).

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you! I'll set it as correct as soon as the time is up.